# My app does not start after screen unlock

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

I used BroadcastReciver to receive if user unlock screen or rebooted phone (user present) and launch activity  but when I unlock screen nothing works 
.
My Idea is to get user state and launch my app several times like pop up advertiser

here is my receiver code :

```
public class recieve extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) || intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) || intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
      Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, serviceonboot.class);
      context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
  }

}
```

and this the service to start when user is present

```
 public class serviceonboot extends Service {

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // here you can add whatever you want this service to do

    startActivity(new Intent(this,BreakActivity.class));
  }
}
```

and here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.zsoft.john.eyeguard">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/eyeguard"
    android:label="Eye Guard"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/eyeguard"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".BreakActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
      android:name="com.zsoft.john.eyeguard.recieve"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.zsoft.john.eyeguard.serviceonboot"></service>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

Override the mathod called onsavedinstatestate and onrestor einstancestate of android activity or fragment.

Comment: how will this help?

Comment: ''' public class BreakActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_break); '''

Comment: have you wrote the onrestoreinstancestate?

Comment: @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_break);
  
  }