# Can not force my app automatically start after screen unlock

Tags: java, android

I want to force my app to start each time I unlock screen.

I looked the questions
[Launch android app on screen unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172605/launch-android-app-on-screen-unlock)
and
[My app does not start after screen unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116846/my-app-does-not-start-after-screen-unlock)
but it looks like to be outdated now.

I would highly appreciate your help! Thank you!